# Where can I find the field names of individual fields in the Address compound field

Tags: apex, data, admin, type

I am pretty new to Salesforce. I have just learned that the Address and Name field in the contact object are compound fields consisting of individual fields. Where can I find the field names of the individual fields inside salesforce? For example, a trailhead challenge that I was doing required me to match the Last name of a contact with a given string. But I cant find a field called Last name inside the object manager of contact object, only the compound field called "Name" with the data type 'Name' is visible. Where can I find the field names of the individual constituent field of name and address compact fields?

Comment: Check the [Object Reference Guide documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) for all objects' field names and other field info.

Answer (score 1):

Address fields have a bunch of different properties, described in [Address Compound Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_address.htm). They all follow the same format. For Mailing Address, for example, you'll have MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingPostalCode, MailingLatitude, etc. Name, on the other hand, can also have a variety of fields, documented in the [Name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_name.htm) object. Not all Name objects are created equal, because this object is used both as compound fields and polymorphic relationships.

In the Classical UI, these fields are separated out:
[image: Contact Name in Classical UI]

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be true for Lighting Experience, there's no way to get at these. However, you can see all the potential values in [Standard Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) documentation. Some fields require enablement before you can use them, like `MiddleName`.